# How to pass map to AWS cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-java-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I have a metrics map coming from different applications and I want to write them into AWSCloud watch.

How can I do that?

PS: I tried putting them using metrics name and metrics value after parsing whole map, but that does not looks a good approach to me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Cloudwatch should easily be able to keep up with your metric volume so I would just use 1 [`PutMetricDataRequest`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudwatch/model/PutMetricDataRequest.html) for each batch coming in from the source applications and let Cloudwatch do the aggregation.

If you look at [`PutMetricDataRequest`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudwatch/model/PutMetricDataRequest.html) it takes a [`Collection<MetricDatum>`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudwatch/model/MetricDatum.html) which is well suited to receive any number of keys you're receiving from the source applications in a single request.

====

Converting a HashMap to a List is pretty straightforward with the Java8 streams API:

Assuming your map is a key => value map:

```
Map<String, Object> metricMap = new HashMap<>();
metricMap.put("metricKey", 99);
```

You can use the Java8 streams API with map and collect:

```
List<MetricDatum> metrics = metricMap.entrySet().parallelStream()
        .map(map -> new MetricDatum()
                .withMetricName(map.getKey())
                .withUnit(StandardUnit.Count)
                .withValue(Double.valueOf(map.getValue().toString()))
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my case data is coming in form of a HashMap<String,Object>. Basically I have a facade with different subscriber modes (Cloud watch is one of them). The map is pushed to Facade and then it is available to different subscribers. Thus in this case I am getting same hashmap. Are you suggesting I need to iterate over all key and values in hashmap to convert it in MetricDatum map.?

Comment: @Lovey: I would use the Java8 streams API which should make this pretty simple. I've added a code sample to the answer illustrating the operation.

Comment: still same . But thats ok. I got what you are trying to conclude here. Thanks.

Comment: sorry -- perhaps i misunderstood the question. would be happy to help further if you can clarify a bit.